# Unknown characters in netbeans and eclipse on main screen and on runtime

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

I have netbeans and eclipse kepler installed on my laptop, but there are unknown characters present on the screen. How do I even remove them?
I tried searching alot. But nothing seems to help me. I don't even know what's it called. Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks! :)

[How can I remove these characters?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEWzj.png)

[main screen of netbeans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2otz.png)

Comment: Seems like you have installed nb in different language

Comment: Or may be problem with your system font. Did you remove any default fonts from your system?

Comment: No language is the default english language @lkdhruw

Comment: How do i do that? @ChathuraBuddhika

Answer (score 0):

Did you download an incorrect language binary for Eclipse and Netbeans? Or is your default locale for Java set to a locale you don't know about (possibly this could be hi_IN).

Could try reinstalling the English version binaries for your IDE. If nothing works before more investigation is done, you could try changing the locale for java before launching the IDE's.

See this for more information on locale: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/locale-140624.html#using

Comment: I installed netbeans with the default settings.
How do I reinstall the English version binaries?
I tried uninstalling and then reinstalling the whole setup again but its still the same,